# JQuery datepicker date of birth and date of issue setting

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have two datepickers, one is DOB and second one is DateOfIssue

```
$( "#tenth_DOB" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',             
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        modal: false,
        maxDate: "-1",
        yearRange: "1947:2016",
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
            $("#dl_DateofIssue").val("");
            $("#dl_ExpiryDate").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#dl_ExpiryDate").val("");
            $(this).valid();
        }
    });

    $("#tenth_DateofIssue").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

        minDate: new Date(todayYear, todayMonth, today),
        maxDate: -1,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: "-20:+0",
        modal: false,
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd-mm-yy', dateStr);
        d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear());
        //$("#DOB").datepicker("option","maxDate", dateStr)
        d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
        $(this).valid();

        }
    });
```

If a user selects his date of birth, I want to set date of issue as from his date of birth to current date, how can I do that??

For example DOB is 01-01-2000 then I need to set Dateofissue 01-01-2000 to 05-07-2016 enabled, other dates disabled.

Comment: the datepicker ui api has the answer you want, especialy the example of date range https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max. Using minDate equal to DOB and maxDate equal to today.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/s6ggaq5k/

```
$(function(){
    $( "#tenth_DOB" ).datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',             
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        modal: false,
        yearRange: "1947:2016",
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        }
    });

    $("#tenth_DateofIssue").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: -1,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        yearRange: "-20:+0",
        modal: false,
        onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is this?? I dont find the answer in this